# C# LINQ - Edit my query to call a method on the result

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I've seen other answers similar to mine but I'm having a hard time applying it to my case.

I've created a LINQ query that will search through two collections and give me a third collection of items from the second collection whose particular property doesn't match the same property from the first collection:

```
    private void GetOnOffConflicts()
    {
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        if (OnOffConflictLayers != null && OnOffConflictLayers.Count != 0)
        {
            OnOffConflictLayers.Clear();
        }

        var onOffQuery = from target in TargetDrawingLayers
                         from source in SourceDrawingLayers
                         where target.Name == source.Name && target.OnOff != source.OnOff
                         select target;

        ObservableCollection<LayerModel> q = new ObservableCollection<LayerModel>(onOffQuery);
        OnOffConflictLayers = q;
    }
```

Now that I have that third collection of conflicts I can run the following method to correct the conflicts:

```
    private void FixOnOffConflictsClick()
    {
        if (OnOffConflictLayers != null && OnOffConflictLayers.Count != 0)
        {
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();

            foreach (LayerModel onOffConflict in OnOffConflictLayers)
            {
                foreach(LayerModel sourceLayer in SourceDrawingLayers)
                {
                    if(onOffConflict.Name == sourceLayer.Name)
                    {
                        string desiredSetting = sourceLayer.OnOff;
                        da.FixLayerConflict(onOffConflict.Path, onOffConflict.Name, desiredSetting);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to convert that nested foreach loop into a statement that is similar to my first LINQ query, but calls `da.FixLayerConflict();` as part of the query.

Would that be a meaningful improvement over the nested foreach, and how could I go about doing it?

I have tried something like:

```
                var fixOnOffQuery = from conflict in OnOffConflictLayers
                             from source in SourceDrawingLayers
                             where conflict.Name == source.Name && conflict.OnOff != source.OnOff
                             select new
                             {
                                 da.FixLayerConflict(conflict.Path, conflict.Name, source.OnOff)
                             };
```

But I don't know enough about the LINQ syntax to create something that works.

I cannot add the fixing method to the original query, by the way, as it's part of the requirement of the program that the user review the conflicts before action is taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to do the method call within a LINQ query, I would recommend you remove your nested foreach by querying to the items you wish to call your function on, then using that collection within a single foreach.

Something like this would work:

```
var conflictsAndSources = from conflict in OnOffConflictLayers
                          from source in SourceDrawingLayers
                          where conflict.Name == source.Name && conflict.OnOff != source.OnOff
                          select new { Conflict = conflict, Source = source };

foreach(var conflictAndSource in conflictsAndSources)
    da.FixLayerConflict(conflictAndSource.Conflict.Path, conflictAndSource.Conflict.Name, conflictAndSource.Source.OnOff);
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. This seems like a very simple and elegant solution! Problem though, `conflictAndSources` is out of scope and can't be called in the `foreach`. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @Kefka I had a typo in the foreach, where `conflictsAndSources` was `conflictAndSources`. Is that the issue?

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks. I will give this a shot but it looks like it'll work. If it does I'll come back and mark your answer! Thanks again!

Comment: @RickPangburn You can get rid of the extra loop and simply call within your select: `from .... select da.FixLayerConflict(conflict.Path, conflict.Name, cource.OnOff);`

Comment: @jcruz That assumes `FixLayerConflict` is not a void method.

Comment: @jcruz, I actually did give something like that a shot but yeah the method is void and won't work as Jonathan Chase mentioned, but thanks.